# How to set local reminder daily. weekly and monthly?

Tags: android

I am using alarm manager and set daily, weekly and monthly alarm using below code

Register alarm

```
val alarmManager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            getReminderTime(year, month, date, hoursOfTheDay, minute),
            getAlarmIntent(reminderData, alarmId)
        )
```

-> Set Year month, date, hours, and minute

set pending intent

```
private fun getAlarmIntent(reminderData: Reminder, alarmId: Int): PendingIntent {

     val intent = Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
     intent.putExtra("alarmId", alarmId)
     return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, alarmId, intent, 0)
 }
```

-> in alarm receiver, I am receiving action or intent data and send simple notification and also set again new alarm.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
            android:name=".receiver.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

 <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.BootCompletedReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Permissions:-

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

so above code is used for daily weekly and monthly alarm but problem is that after few minute like 10 to 15 my alarm is not fired in action so my receiver is not called.

Can anyone help to find solutions?

Thank you